# Creating endless copies of objects

Tags: excel, vba, object, standards

I have a macro which theoretically works perfectly but I think it is creating unnecessary processing and calculation requirements which then crashes the file. It's in a file which I use regularly so maybe the problem is getting worse over time as well- hard to say. In the VBA Project window under Microsoft Excel Objects I have endless copies of all objects referenced which seem to have been created automatically ie

```
Sheet11
Sheet111
Sheet1111

ThisWorkbook
ThisWorkbook1
ThisWorkbook10
ThisWorkbook11
etc...
```

Does anyone know why this is/if it's an issue? If it's an issue how do I get rid of it?

The other related question I have is that I've been using the following macro to access data in a workbook without fully opening it, but I'm concerned that the wb.close command doesn't work when the workbook is open as a background process ie I suspect that maybe the workbook stays open in the background, slowing things down. Below is an example of the code which does this:

```
Dim xlApp As Application

Set xlApp = GetObject("X:\Power\UK\GA\doc.xlsx")
Set wbcheck = xlApp.Workbooks("doc.xlsx")

'Do stuff!!

wbcheck.Close False
```

Apologies that this is a fairly general question but essentially I want to write cleaner code that won't make my spreadsheet crash!

Thanks

Rachel

Comment: When you see that in the VB editor it's a good sign your workbook is corrupted - copy everything to a new workbook and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Why don't you share the complete procedure? Why are you using `GetObject`? It obviously doesn't work as intended: `GetObject("X:\Power\UK\GA\doc.xlsx")` will reference a workbook, not an application.

Comment: _access data in a workbook without fully opening it_ - might be easier to use PowerQuery rather than VBA to grab data out of another workbook.  `Dim wbCheck As Workbook: Set wbCheck = Workbooks.Open("X:\Power\UK\GA\doc.xlsx")` would be the VBA way to open the workbook.